# How can I perform an asynchronous operation before grunt.initConfig()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs

Now I have my Gruntfile setup to perform some automatic detection magic like parsing sourcefiles to parse some PHP sources in roder to dynamically figure out filenames and paths I need to know before running `grunt.initConfig()`.

Unfortunately `grunt.initConfig()` doesn't seem to be meant to be run asynchronously, so I see no way to have my asynchronous code executed before I can call it. Is there a trick to accomplish this or do I have to rewrite my detection routines synchronously? Is there any easy way to block execution before my callback has arrived?

Inside grunt tasks there is of course `this.async()`, but for `initConfig()` that doesn't work.

Here's a stripped down example:

```js
function findSomeFilesAndPaths(callback) {
  // async tasks that detect and parse
  // and execute callback(results) when done
}

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var config = {
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  }

  findSomeFilesAndPaths(function (results) {
    config.watch = {
      coffee: {
        files: results.coffeeDir + "**/*.coffee",
        tasks: ["coffee"]
         // ...
      }
    };

    grunt.initConfig(config);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-coffee"
    // grunt.loadNpmTasks(...);
  });
};
```

Any good ideas how to get this done?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens if you just put grunt.initconfig and grunt.loadnpmtasks etc in the callback from the async function?

Comment: Isn't that what I did above? What happens is that grunt does not wait for my callback, so `grunt.initConfig()` etc. will not be called before the grunt client returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by rewriting, synchronous style. [ShellJS](http://shelljs.org/) came in handy, especially for synchronously executing shell commands.

Answer (score 7):

I would do it as a task since Grunt is sync or if you can make `findSomeFilesAndPaths` sync.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  initData: {},
  watch: {
    coffee: {
      files: ['<%= initData.coffeeDir %>/**/*.coffee'],
      tasks: ['coffee'],
    },
  },
});

grunt.registerTask('init', function() {
  var done = this.async();
  findSomeFilesAndPaths(function(results) {
    // Set our initData in our config
    grunt.config(['initData'], results);
    done();
  });
});

// This is optional but if you want it to
// always run the init task first do this
grunt.renameTask('watch', 'actualWatch');
grunt.registerTask('watch', ['init', 'actualWatch']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kyle, your solution is very helpful for that minimal example. In fact I might have multiple directories for scripts and stylesheets and lots of other tasks which will only be known at runtime, like automatic downloads and decompression (all of this did work fine with rake, but for various reasons I want to switch to grunt). I might get this to work this way, but it would be much easier and cleaner to have the whole config object ready before calling `grunt.initConfig()`. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Since Grunt is sync you unfortunately can't without writing your own grunt-cli; which would be more cumbersome than the above solution, imo.

Comment: I guess you're right. Just opened an [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/783) on GitHub, anyway.

Comment: Rather than replacing existing tasks that rely on the config data, you can just add `grunt.task.run('init')` to the script, to ensure it runs before Grunt starts running any tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Example of how you could use ShellJS in Grunt:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    paths: {
        bootstrap: exec('bundle show bootstrap-sass').output.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '')
    },
    uglify: {
        vendor: {
            files: { 'vendor.js': ['<%= paths.bootstrap %>/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js']
        }
    }
});
```