# grunt.initConfig in a callback does not work

Tags: deployment, callback, gruntjs

I want to use grunt for deployment and therefore want to read in configuration of remote hosts  based on the already existing `~/.ssh/config` file.

To load that configuration I'm using [sshconf](https://npmjs.org/package/sshconf) but need to include the `grunt.initConfig()` call in the callback to have the configuration when defining environments.

```
var sshconf = require('sshconf');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Read in ssh configuration
  sshconf.read(function(err, sshHosts) {

    if (err)
      console.log(err);

    // SSH config loaded, now init grunt

    grunt.initConfig({
      sshconfig: {
        staging: {
          privateKey: grunt.file.read(sshHosts['project_staging'].properties.IdentityFile),
          host: sshHosts['project_staging'].properties.HostName,
          username: sshHosts['project_staging'].properties.User,
          port: sshHosts['project_staging'].properties.Port || 22,
          path: "/var/www/project"
        },
        production: {
          // ...
        }
      },
      // Tasks to be executed on remote server
      sshexec: {
        example_task: {
          command: 'uptime && hostname'
        }
      },
      sftp: {
        deploy: {
          files: {
            "./": ["*.json", "*.js", "config/**", "controllers/**", "lib/**", "models/**", "public/**", "views/**"]
          },
          options: {
            //srcBasePath: "test/",
            createDirectories: true
          }
        }
      }
      // More tasks
      // ...
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ssh');
    // More plugins ...
  });

};
```

When I call `grunt --help` it states:

```
> grunt --help
Grunt: The JavaScript Task Runner (v0.4.1)
…
Available tasks
(no tasks found)
```

If I do not wrap the grunt initiation in that callback (`sshconf.read(function(err, sshHosts) {})`) everything is working fine (except for the ssh config not loaded or not yet ready to be used).

Is what I am trying even possible and if so, how? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grunt init cannot be used in an async fashion like this. Either read the sshconf synchronously, or use a task, as described in this answer: [How can I perform an asynchronous operation before grunt.initConfig()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547528/how-can-i-perform-an-asynchronous-operation-before-grunt-initconfig)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I implemented it the way it's said in the linked answer and it's working. Still a little bit of overhead but if I add tasks independent from `ssh`'ing this solution might be even better.