# List files and display them with Jade (read: pass async dataf to Jade by Grunt)

Tags: asynchronous, gruntjs, pug

I have a trouble to pass data from async module (https://github.com/jergason/recursive-readdir, to be honest every async operation is a problem - fs.readdir too).

I wish Grunt would have native method like: grunt.file.readJSON() to recursive read  directory...

At beginning I made a simple module with recursive-readdir and included it straight to Gruntfile.js (no effect), but after reading Grunt doc, the this.async comes on my way. Even though still cannot pass async file list from recursive-readdir to Jade template:

**SPECIFIED TASK**

```
var recursive = require('recursive-readdir'); 

grunt.registerTask('readFileList', 'Lists recursively files list. from given path', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    var fileList = recursive('somePath', function (err, files) {
        console.log('log files: ', files);
    });

    done(fileList);
    grunt.config.set('readyList', fileList);
 });
```

**INIT CONFIG**

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    config: {
        list: grunt.config.get('readyList')
}...
```

**INCLUDING DATA**

```
jade: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            pretty: true,
            data: {
                asyncData: grunt.config.list
                //asyncData: fs.readdirSync('.tmp')
            }
        }...
```

The "working" repo to my issue: https://github.com/cachaito/grunt_list_files is created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547528/how-can-i-perform-an-asynchronous-operation-before-grunt-initconfig/#answer-16549510) I found the solution:

**SPECIFIED TASK**

```
grunt.registerTask('readFileList', 'Lists recursively files list. from given path', function() {

    var done = this.async();

    var fileList = recursive('./.tmp', function (err, files) {
        grunt.config(['initData'], files);
        console.log('RECIEVED FILES: ', files);
        done();
    });
});
```

**INIT CONFIG**

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    initData: {}...
```

**INCLUDING DATA**

```
jade: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            pretty: true,
            data: {
                asyncData: '<%= initData %>'
            }
        }...
```

Hope this will help someone. Git repo is updated.